# Do not award bounty for community wiki answers

Tags: feature-request, bounty, community-wiki

From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):

> Community wiki posts are more easily editable by all users, and do not
>   confer any reputation.

That is not true.  I just received a bounty for my community wiki answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22815549/409172).

My answer is relatively simple and was already provided by several people in the comments.  I thought community wiki would be a good way to answer the question without stealing anyone's internet points.  Is this feature left over from the days when posts were automatically converted to community wiki, and the original poster may still want the bounty?

1. Would it be possible to modify the bounty system to not award bounty points to the owner of a community wiki answer?
2. If not, can you modify the Help Center explanation about community wiki posts and reputation?

Comment: `Can you remove 400 points from my account and donate them to a starving unicorn?` Couldn't you just find some answer you like and "pay it forward"?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Yes, I can do that.  But I already do that for fun, it would still feel like "cheating".

Comment: It's actually a dastardly plan to reward those truly honourable by giving them rep, whether they like it or not.

Comment: The approved way of discarding your ill-gotten gains (if you really think them such), is just posting bounties for the amount to deserving questions in need of better answers, or with superb answers which are undervalued. I think neither is quite as scarce as unicorns though.

Comment: Ok, I'll just give those points away myself this time.  I edited the question to remove that option so it doesn't distract from my main requests.

Comment: As I remember it you've already put quite a few bounties on other people's questions... this might be providence paying you back against your wishes :-).

Comment: Here's an example where someone's just set a bounty on a CW question (!). That feels like it shouldn't be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript